# ODATA Filter with ServiceBus Queues

Tags: c#, odata, servicebus

I'm sorry, this might be a dumb question, but I can't get the filter right.
How do I filter the queues for a queue with a path that starts with `bob_`?

I tried:

```
namespaceManager.GetQueues("startswith(path, 'bob_')");
```

and:

```
namespaceManager.GetQueues("startswith('bob_')");
```

and:

```
namespaceManager.GetQueues("'bob_'");
```

But it didn't work -_-

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found it!

```
namespaceManager.GetQueues("startswith(path, 'bob_') eq true");
```